# How to unique values from different nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have below xml

input:

```
<Records count="1">
<Record contentId="2410630" levelId="442" levelGuid="29c1b6a4-b7db-49dc-a703-e78aa1b1246a" moduleId="875" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="2410631" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208294" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208294</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410632" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208289" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208289</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410633" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208270" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Loss of Systems Including Data Center</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208270</Field>
        </Record>   
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410636" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208289" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208289</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410661" levelId="463" levelGuid="cc59604e-cc41-4253-879a-5fbde3ffd760" moduleId="896" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41541" guid="bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208289">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Reference>
        </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410666" levelId="463" levelGuid="cc59604e-cc41-4253-879a-5fbde3ffd760" moduleId="896" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41541" guid="bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208273"> Loss of 50% Staff </Reference>
        </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410649" levelId="462" levelGuid="83a26d99-e79d-41af-8a20-fa069f791cef" moduleId="895" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41453" guid="9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208328">Technology Configuration</Reference>
        </Field>
    </Record>
</Record>
</Records>
```

Expected Output:

```
    <uniqueValues>Inadequate Information Security Practices</uniqueValues>
    <uniqueValues>Loss of Systems Including Data Center</uniqueValues>
    <uniqueValues>Loss of 50% Staff</uniqueValues>
    <uniqueValues>Technology Configuration</uniqueValues>
```

Here is my code

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
   
  <xsl:variable name ="fields" select="//Metadata/FieldDefinitions" />
   

  <!--match the root node-->
  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <ArcherRecords>
      
      <xsl:for-each select="Record[@levelGuid='29c1b6a4-b7db-49dc-a703-e78aa1b1246a']">
          <xsl:variable name="valuesTobeCompared" select="Record/Field[@guid='bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6']/Reference/@id"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Record/Record" group-by="./Field[@guid='24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373']">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$valuesTobeCompared = ./Field[@guid='24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373']">
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                 <uniqueValues><xsl:value-of select="./Field[@guid='24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373']"/></uniqueValues>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ArcherRecords>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it is only giving first set of unique values but I want all unique values from entire record set along with it should also have one value of duplicated value, I was not sure how to get all node values into one variable I am able to store only one node values into variable,
Could anybody help me how to write a xslt code to get the unique values

group-by itself will retrieve unique values from provided selectpath, but how can I give multiple node-set values to for-each-group

Comment: It is hard to identify the criteria you have to select the shown data as unique. Perhaps explain in plain text which elements you want to select.

Comment: Why is "Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External", for instance, not selected?

Comment: I want to all unique elements from all the records(field guidid 2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753 , bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6 , 9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5) problem is I have 3 different field sets

Comment: What you described in your comment I would translate into the XPath expression `distinct-values(Records/Record/Record/Field[@guid = ('2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753', 'bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6', '9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5')]/Reference)` but that gives three values `Inadequate Information Security Practices`, ` Loss of 50% Staff`, `Technology Configuration` so one value is missing. Still not sure what you name a "field set" and how to express that in XPath but doing e.g. `distinct-values((//foo, //bar, //baz))` is easily possible.

Comment: I tried with distinct values ``` <xsl:template match="Records">
    <ArcherRecords>
      <xsl:for-each select="Record[@levelGuid='29c1b6a4-b7db-49dc-a703-e78aa1b1246a']">
          <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values((Record/Record/Field[@guid ='2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753'],Record/Record/Field[@guid ='bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6']/Reference))">
             <ArcherRecord>
                <uniqueValues><xsl:value-of select="."/></uniqueValues>
            </ArcherRecord>
          </xsl:for-each> 
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ArcherRecords>
  </xsl:template>```

Comment: I got distinct values but If I give any xpath inside that for-loop it is giving error " The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(), but the supplied expression {.} has item type xs:anyAtomicType"

Comment: `distinct-values` indeed gives you a sequence of atomic values but doing e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values((//foo, //bar))"><unique-value><xsl:value-of select="."/></unique-value></xsl:for-each>` should work and should not give an error. Why you expect to use "any xpath" if presented with that function called `distinct-values` and being told it gives values like a `Inadequate Information Security Practices, Loss of 50% Staff, Technology Configuration` is not clear to me.

Comment: I have other values inside each record along with distinct values I want those values also to be captured

Comment: like this <Record contentId="2410631"  levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be"><Record contentId="2208294" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d"><Field guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753">Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External</Field>
<Field  guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" >2208294</Field></Record><Field  guid="7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296">Cyber - 1</Field>
<Field guid="001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f" >Is all software that will be used for this initiative currently approved for use?</Field</Record>

Comment: I want to capture "Is all software that will be used for this initiative currently approved for use" value with respect to each distinct value

Comment: I am afraid your expected output for the original question are four elements with four different values so don't change your requirements later, ask a new question if necessary. I am not sure if this one is solved as the sample data with all those longish guids and all your explanations and comments so far haven't made it clear to me what you are after.

Comment: can I achieve same thing(get the distinct values from different xpaths) using for-each or for-each-group

Comment: Well, the sequence operator `,` is part of XPath 2 so you can use it in any XPath 2 expression (which the `select` of `for-each-group` is, which the `select` of `for-each` is, why also the `group-by` of `for-each-group` is). Whether it is going to make sense for your sample data I am not sure, as I said, longish guids and convoluted code snippets haven't exactly made it easy to grasp how to sample input and the initial expected output are related.

Comment: I have posted my new expected value in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74943042/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-different-xpaths-in-xslt could you please help me out