# How to get distinct values from different xpaths in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I would like to achieve distinct values from the given input file using xslt

here is my input:

```
<Records count="1">
<Record contentId="2410630" levelId="442" levelGuid="29c1b6a4-b7db-49dc-a703-e78aa1b1246a" moduleId="875" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="2410631" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208294" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208294</Field>
            <Field  guid="7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296">Cyber - 1</Field>
            <Field guid="001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f" >Is all software that will be used for this initiative currently approved for use within</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410632" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208289" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208289</Field>
            <Field id="41131" guid="7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296" type="1">Cyber - 10</Field>
            <Field id="41132" guid="001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f" type="1">Will there be a requirement to connect a 3rd party to xxxxx network and what would be the purpose of this connection?</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410633" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208270" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Loss of Systems Including Data Center</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208270</Field>
            <Field id="41131" guid="7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296" type="1">Cyber - 11</Field>
            <Field id="41132" guid="001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f" type="1">Is this product or service hosted or recovered </Field>
        </Record>   
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410636" levelId="458" levelGuid="67dbf848-5352-4953-a25b-1b1bbcde89be" moduleId="891" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="2208289" levelId="330" levelGuid="d25cfb04-eb2a-423c-bdab-2db21a58fd4d" moduleId="675" parentId="0">
            <Field id="31799" guid="2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753" type="1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
            <Field id="31796" guid="24640c19-d1de-415b-b349-25b0af521373" type="6">2208289</Field>
            <Field id="41131" guid="7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296" type="1">Cyber - 3</Field>
            <Field id="41132" guid="001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f" type="1">Define the Data Classification</Field>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410661" levelId="463" levelGuid="cc59604e-cc41-4253-879a-5fbde3ffd760" moduleId="896" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41541" guid="bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208289">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="41485" guid="6fe04171-26b5-4bad-9430-d6d3d592c404" type="1">QL1 - LS Test - Architecture</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410666" levelId="463" levelGuid="cc59604e-cc41-4253-879a-5fbde3ffd760" moduleId="896" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41541" guid="bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208273"> Loss of 50% Staff </Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="41485" guid="6fe04171-26b5-4bad-9430-d6d3d592c404" type="1">QL3 - LS Test - Architecture</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="2410649" levelId="462" levelGuid="83a26d99-e79d-41af-8a20-fa069f791cef" moduleId="895" parentId="0">
        <Field id="41453" guid="9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5" type="9">
            <Reference id="2208328">Technology Configuration</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field id="41397" guid="c9574505-854b-44c2-aa4c-4a419c80b1e6" type="1">DG - Analytics</Field>
    </Record>
</Record>
</Records>
```

My expected output is :

```
<Record> 
        <uniqueValues>Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External</uniqueValues>
        <cyber>Cyber - 1</cyber>
        <question>Is all software that will be used for this initiative currently approved for use within</question>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <uniqueValues>Inadequate Information Security Practices</uniqueValues>
        <cyber>Cyber - 10</cyber>
        <question>Will there be a requirement to connect a 3rd party to xxxxx network and what would be the purpose of this connection?</question>
    </Record>
    <Record> 
        <uniqueValues>Loss of Systems Including Data Center</uniqueValues>
        <cyber>Cyber - 11</cyber>
        <question>Is this product or service hosted or recovered </question>
    </Record>
    <Record>
         <uniqueValues>Loss of 50% Staff</uniqueValues>
        <question>QL3 - LS Test - Architecture</question> 
    </Record>
    <Record> 
        <uniqueValues>Technology Configuration</uniqueValues>
        <question>DG - Analytics</question>
    </Record>
```

I have tried using distinct values but it is giving me only atomic values i can't able to capture remining field values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="Records">
    
       <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values((Record/Record/Field[@guid ='2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753'],Record/Record/Field[@guid ='bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6']/Reference,Record/Record/Field[@guid ='9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5']/Reference))">
             <Record>
                <uniqueValues><xsl:value-of select="."/></uniqueValues>
            </Record>
          </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this gives only distinct values
Could you please help me how can i write an xslt to get the expected output

Comment: Does the posted `distinct-values` sample at least return the 5 unique values you show in the expected records? Posting code that doesn't do the job and not explaining in plain English the exact grouping population and grouping key(s?) doesn't allow us to tell what you are looking for. Perhaps spend some time with the samples using `group-by` in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info to see and understand how the grouping works to get a change to apply it to your own data.

Comment: I used for-each-group as well but i am only able to give one xpath in group-by my question is how can i give multiple xpaths in for-each-group

Comment: With all the comments we exchanged on your previous question you should have grasped by now that you can do `xsl:for-each-group select="//foo, //bar, //baz"` syntactically just fine. What you need/want in the `group-by` requires a precise textual explanation of your grouping requirements and/or perhaps a simplification of the sample data to not expect us to simply infer from longish and lots of guids what might be your grouping keys.

Comment: The `group-by` expression is evaluated with each item in the grouping population as the context item thus while doing e.g. `group-by="key1-expression, key2-expression, key3-expression"` is possible of course semantically it only makes sense if you ensure those expressions select a single key for each item (or the same number of multiple keys if you use/want that XSLT 3 feature).

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you so much for the help, It is working now.I have added xsl:for-each-group select="//foo, //bar, //baz", it is picking distinct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Records">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Record/Record" group-by="Record/Field[@guid ='2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753'], Field[@guid = ('bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6', '9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5')]/Reference">
        <xsl:copy>
          <uniqueValues>{current-grouping-key()}</uniqueValues>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Field[@guid = '7de0f37f-765a-4480-bbea-da1638ab3296']">
    <cyber>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </cyber>
  </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="Field[@guid = ('001a8562-9091-4e42-b96a-d17c33c19f6f', '6fe04171-26b5-4bad-9430-d6d3d592c404', 'c9574505-854b-44c2-aa4c-4a419c80b1e6')]">
    <question>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </question>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
<Records>
   <Record>
      <uniqueValues>Unauthorized modification of Information/System - External</uniqueValues>
      <cyber>Cyber - 1</cyber>
      <question>Is all software that will be used for this initiative currently approved for use within</question>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <uniqueValues>Inadequate Information Security Practices</uniqueValues>
      <cyber>Cyber - 10</cyber>
      <question>Will there be a requirement to connect a 3rd party to xxxxx network and what would be the purpose of this connection?</question>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <uniqueValues>Loss of Systems Including Data Center</uniqueValues>
      <cyber>Cyber - 11</cyber>
      <question>Is this product or service hosted or recovered </question>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <uniqueValues> Loss of 50% Staff </uniqueValues>
      <question>QL3 - LS Test - Architecture</question>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <uniqueValues>Technology Configuration</uniqueValues>
      <question>DG - Analytics</question>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

Of course the `group-by` expression with a sequence i.e. `group-by="Record/Field[@guid ='2ebbfd8e-3e89-4be5-9c1f-1b5e85950753'], Field[@guid = ('bae76db7-4e46-4113-a453-68243a76d4f6', '9a764db7-a75e-4a49-9b26-de03e2bc4bb5')]/Reference"` will only work if for each item in the grouping population only one of the subexpressions selects a key value and the other ones select the empty sequence.